# Запуск сервера на нод js и открытие браузера через PowerShell

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell

Есть задача: при нажатии на ярлык запустить сервер node.js, после этого открыть браузер хром с указаным URL. Как это можно реализовать? Можно простой пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Start-Process node server_demo.js -WindowStyle Hidden
Start-Process http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Первая команда запускает нужный вам файл в спрятанном окне. Если вам нужно, чтобы окошко nodejs отобразилось, уберите параметр `-WindowStyle Hidden`

Вторая команда запускает  браузер по умолчанию с указанным URL. Соответственно необходимо установить хром браузером по умолчанию.